# Как перейти к определенному элементу матрицы из текстового файла?

Tags: c++, boost

Есть матрица, записанная в cvs файл. В качестве разделителя используется символ ';'.

```
29;89;77;56;7;40;100;29;57;60;
49;4;44;51;86;37;25;54;51;61;
5;93;55;15;37;92;68;54;28;48;
83;48;16;50;93;20;64;76;78;42;
96;1;100;57;45;53;63;97;22;47;
84;25;76;61;31;52;53;90;46;5;
17;43;23;49;84;34;26;1;63;52;
68;54;48;96;83;37;34;37;96;92;
27;70;58;41;94;48;14;89;99;86;
40;21;66;98;40;78;72;27;72;76;
```

Необходимо перейти к определенному элементу в матрице (в последующем этот элемент нужно будет заменить) и вывести его. Числа случайные и необязательно двухзначные.

Залип на этот моменте

```
    cpp_int getElementInFile(fstream &file, unsigned int size, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    cpp_int toReturn;
    cpp_int temp;
    string test;
    int sizeOfElement = (sizeof(cpp_int) + sizeof(';'));
    streampos saveCurrentCursor = file.tellg();//сохраняем позицию курсора
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);//переходим на начало файла
    file.seekg(((i-1)*size+(j-1))*sizeOfElement, ios::cur);
    file >> test;
    cout << test;
    return toReturn;
}
```

Полный исходник [тут](https://pastebin.com/7kcdNWQX)

Comment: Они же могут быть разного размера... При чем же тут `int sizeOfElement = (sizeof(cpp_int) + sizeof(';'));`?

Comment: Это да. Я уже думал записывать файл в бинарном виде, но тогда будет неудобно редактировать исходный файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше делать разделение через пробел, так работать проще.
В моем доке Ваши числа хранятся через пробел, так все работает.

```
std::ifstream file("doc.txt");
int arr[10][10];
for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (auto j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        file >> arr[i][j];
    }
}
for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (auto j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Таким образом в массиве, который Вы можете создать, вы можете изменить элемент, который вам нужно, после чего перезаписать данные из этого двумерного массива в Ваш файл.

Comment: А в чем смысл копировать файл в stringstream? Можно было бы вместо `ss >> arr[i][j]` сделать `file >> arr[i][j]`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо, буду знать